# GeoTIFF to Web Mercator (tiles)

Tags: coordinate-system, gdal2tiles

I was georeferencing a map. (it’s now a working map in the GeoTIFF format) Then I used

```
gdal2tiles -z5-11 myFile.tif myFolder
```

but the resulting tiles were incompatible with Mapbox and compared to working ones it seems as if it would be using some different projection.
I used `gdalwarp` to convert the GeoTIFF to the correct ESPG:3857 format but the tiles are in the same format. I also tried to add the `gdal2tiles -p mercator` option but it didn’t change it the expected way.

How can I generate ESPG:3857 tiles?

Comment: I suspect you're probably close. There are actually two popular tiling schemes. Relative to Leaflet's `L.tileLayer` implementation, there are `"tms": true`, and `"tms": false`. Which ever one you use will depend upon which scheme the tiles were created to accommodate. So, assuming you have a Leaflet map (after all you're talking about Mapbox), you might try swapping that tms value. If you're `L.tileLayer` implementation doesn't set that option/value, try adding it and running it as either true/false to see if one or the other works.

Comment: Related to my earlier comment, I see gdal2tiles also has a [`--xyz` parameter](https://gdal.org/programs/gdal2tiles.html#cmdoption-gdal-translate-xyz). It looks like it should be the TMS-proper format by default, but I'm not sure how you're consuming the tiles you generated. I still think it would be worth flipping the `tms=true` option on/off to see if things come to life in your project.

Answer (score 1):

In the end adding the `- - xyz` parameter to the `gdal2tiles` command, as suggested in the comments above by “elrobis” made it working correctly.